# Selecting range with a variable VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to select a range that will go from A9 A&"n" (meaning that n is a number that will vary each time i run the macro.

I cannot seem to find a formula that allows me to do this. Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you looking to [find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)?

Comment: `Range("A9:A" & n).Select` (where `n > 0`)

Comment: @brax It doesn't seem to work - it highlights the last line in yellow when i type this: Range("A9:A" & a).Paste

Comment: @bigben that was the initial goal but given that i am using based on elements in the column on the right, thought of counting how many rows there are in the column to the right and then pasting the formula in column A until A&"n"

Comment: Don't use Select and Copy/Paste - just assign the values directly.

Comment: it worked thank you @brax

Comment: When asking a question, please create a [reprex].